# How to use a heredoc with the Rscript command

Tags: r, linux, bash, heredoc, rscript

Using a heredoc in place of a text file seems to work with `python`:

```
(base) balter@exahead1:~$ python <<EOF
print("hello")
EOF
hello
```

However, it doesn't seem to work with `Rscript`:

```
(base) balter@exahead1:~$ Rscript <<EOF
print("hello")
EOF
Usage: Rscript [options] file [args]
   or: Rscript [options] -e expr [-e expr2 ...] [args]
A binary front-end to R, for use in scripting applications.

Options:
  --help              Print usage and exit
  --version           Print version and exit
  --verbose           Print information on progress
  --default-packages=LIST  Attach these packages on startup;
                        a comma-separated LIST of package names, or 'NULL'
and options to R (in addition to --no-echo --no-restore), for example:
  --save              Do save workspace at the end of the session
  --no-environ        Don't read the site and user environment files
  --no-site-file      Don't read the site-wide Rprofile
  --no-init-file      Don't read the user R profile
  --restore           Do restore previously saved objects at startup
  --vanilla           Combine --no-save, --no-restore, --no-site-file,
                        --no-init-file and --no-environ

Expressions (one or more '-e <expr>') may be used *instead* of 'file'.
Any additional 'args' can be accessed from R via 'commandArgs(TRUE)'.
See also  ?Rscript  from within R.
```

As a test, it does work with a text file:

```
(base) balter@exahead1:~$ cat test.R
print("hello")
(base) balter@exahead1:~$ Rscript test.R
[1] "hello"
```

Comment: Heredoc is not a clean file, thus Rscript is not able to open it as a handle. You can do something similar invoking `R -s --vanilla <<EOF ...` - `R` expects commands input. If you can live with every line result being printed, this should be sufficient.

Comment: I suggest: `Rscript - << EOF`

Comment: https://colinfay.me/intro-to-r/appendix-b-invoking-r.html